# LESS (dynamic style sheet language) and Resource Loaders

Tags: javascript, css, less, yepnope, resource-loading

I am currently looking at changing from using css to [LESS](http://lesscss.org) in my current project. A few things to mention before I get to the question are:

1) The project is purely clientside (Html/Js/Css) so there is no server side component for the website (although there is a web service it calls via CORS)
2) I load almost everything via resource loading frameworks, currently I am using yepnope

So given the above I need to be able to get the LESS styles to be processed clientside, but as I am using a resource loader and more css/less *could* be loaded after the initial page load has happened I was wondering if:

1) Does Less work with content loaders when using client side processing? As it says:

```
Client-side usage

Link your .less stylesheets with the rel set to “stylesheet/less”:

<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
Then download less.js from the top of the page, and include it in the <head> element of your page, like so:

<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
Make sure you include your stylesheets before the script.
```

I think I *may* be able to tell yepnope how to handle less files and give them the required element attributes. If I can providing the less resources are brought in before the less javascript will it be ok?

2) Is there any manual way to tell it what to process in javascript?

This would cover the case where everything has been loaded for the current page, the user clicks a button which dynamically loads a new template which is displayed in the current page, this *may* require new less resources to be loaded, but the less.js file has already been included.

Hopefully the above gives you some context as to what I am trying to do and what the 2 questions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Reading this post [Load less.js rules dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175013/load-less-js-rules-dynamically) and adjusting it a bit:

```
less.sheets.push(document.getElementById('new-style-1'));
// Add the new less file to the head of your document    
var newLessStylesheet = $("<link />").attr("id", "new-style-1").attr("href", "/stylesheets/style.less").attr("type", 'text/less');
$("head").append(newLessStylesheet);
// Have less refresh the stylesheets
less.refresh(true);
```

You could also generate all the CSS in your development environment and put it in one file.
There are lots of options. The easiests way would be to use an application. You could use apps like http://incident57.com/less/ for Mac. You can even compile online: Search for something as "lessphp".

Comment: I know of the server side solutions, I just wanted to evaluate things purely clientside, as some of the variables assigned may be based on screen size and some other client specific information, which would just not be available on the server. However forgetting that I think you have solved my problem :)

Comment: You could off course also go for media queries in your css/less to have styling depending on screen size.

By width: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width
Or by heigth: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#height