# Changing variable dynamically (at runtime) via LESS and CSS?

Tags: html, css, less

```
@myThemeBackground = #ddd;  

div#box1 { background: @myThemeBackground; }
```

I'm using LESS in order to use variables for my css. It works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a way for me to change the "myThemeBackground" dynamically at runtime via javascript or something.

So say if the user chooses a custom color for the background I'd like the entire skin to change.

Note: this is for dynamically theming/skinning an application where the user chooses the color for the background for example and then the whole app changes (without a page refresh)

Comment: How many colours were you targeting? A set of predefined colours or an unlimited choice of colours?

Comment: Unlimited choice of colors that a user could select from a color picker.

Comment: note: this is an old question, css variables do this now.

Answer (score 14):

You can modify Less variables on the fly using the modifyVars method:

```
less.modifyVars({ myThemeBackground : '#000' });
```

Comment: This is not working for me with less-1.3.3.min.js. Nothing happens when I use `modifyVars` either like you've shown or by passing an argument like `{'@myThemeBackground': '#000'}`.

Comment: I have the same problem - is there any way to make less.modifyVars work in the current version 1.3.3?

Comment: What exactely doesn't work? Does the less global exist? The modifyVars method? Any error messages? 1.3.3 changelog doesn't mention any important changes.

Answer (score 1):

I usually grab the CSS generated by LESS and include that in a file to optimize the web page loading speed. In fact, I use [LESS.app](http://incident57.com/less/) for Mac to generate my CSS.

To my knowledge, part of the solution would involve including `less.js` file to your page. This in turn means that generating the style of the page would be slow and the caching might cause you some trouble too...

I would humbly suggest generating multiple CSS stylesheets with LESS and include these files when needed with JavaScript.

Comment: +1 Very sound advice.  In some situations you might consider generating more static files on the server at runtime.  This allows for caching, faster rendering, and faster download.

Comment: Not sure if you understood my question. I'm looking for a way in runtime to change a Less variable and have it apply to my page. So If I set myThemeBackground to Blue then my page's background will dynamically have that color.

Comment: @foreyez I understood the question. I am working on solution right now.

Comment: thanks, I'm thinking if maybe there's a way to add the less variable in javascript and then do a less.refreshStyles() or something.. like you load the initial .less css file. and then in javascript you change one of the variables, and then you do a less.refreshStyles() somethign along those lines anyway..

Comment: I was looking into a server side solution that involves AJAX and node.js.

Comment: ah, i'm looking for a client side only solution... but thanks

Comment: Alright. Only consider that it might be bothersome for users to have a delay from the generation of the CSS from LESS on each page request. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to change the text you render with less.js, with:

```
less.refreshStyles()
```

Change the text in the file or in the less snippet of styling.

Read more about it here:
[Load less.js rules dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175013/load-less-js-rules-dynamically)