# "correct" way to have user customized CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, customization

I'm making a web app that is VERY customizable (colors, etc). I am trying to find the easiest way to make this easy for me to develop. The best thing I've come up with so far is to have [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)-like CSS code and replace the stuff with values from `localStorage` through JavaScript, like this:

CSS code:

```
<style id="customsheet">
.someclass{
background-color:[classBackground];
color:[classColor]
}
#anelement{
font-family:[eltFont];
font-size:[eltFontSize];
}
</style>
```

And replace, for example, `[eltFont]` with `localStorage.eltFont` using JavaScript, which modifies the `innerHTML` of the `<style>` element.

What I'm asking is, is there a better/"correct" way to do this? The way I thought up seems...weird.

Comment: I wouldn't use a real `<style>` tag as it will be parsed initially (and i'm not so sure if it will be parsed again if it's modified). Instead store the declarations in a template, copy the innerhtml, modify it and then create a `<style>` tag.

Comment: If you haven't already, you might want to read about LESS ([SO Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946873/changing-variable-dynamically-at-runtime-via-less-and-css)) or a similar css lib.

Comment: @nietonfir good point, do you think a `<script type="x-css/x-custom">` would be a good way to do that? @mseifert I try to stay away from libraries like that, sorry

Comment: My first idea is to create different themes. Each theme would have a consistent style. The user could pick a theme and this information is stored locally.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree I need it to be fully customizeable, sorry

Comment: If you can work with classes and can have multiple classes per element, take a look [here](Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript).

Comment: Missing link from above: [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951)