# Using CSS variables in MVC view (w/ bootstrap)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I would like to have different navbar's design according to user login.

Not only the options available (in the menu) but also css definitions (colors, and so on...).
Is it possible to define them as variables maintaining for example the bootstrap scheme.
For exchanging colors I saw:

[Change navbar color in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3) 
answered by Skelly

It does solve my problem. 
I need the colors (...) to be decided only when the view is generated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean "It does NOT solve my problem."

Comment: You may have to create theme css files that override the Bootstrap colors you want to change, then let the user select the theme they want, save that theme files path in the DB then when the login you can grap that css path and inject in the head after your bootstrap styles

Comment: @MrLister it sounds like he wants to change less variables at runtime and recompile the css file. Like this maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946873/changing-variable-dynamically-at-runtime-via-less-and-css

Comment: @MrLister Thanks, the word "NOT" is missing.

Comment: @zgood first solution seems possible but limited, You have to have all configurations pre-defined (suppose the user only want to change navbar color). 2nd solution, I don´t know less. Do you have any example fitting the problem. (and thanks for the answers).