# How to wait for LESS JS to load the .less file?

Tags: javascript, less, domready

My webpage includes a `less` file instead of `css`. This is parsed by the `less` js script. My site's js script fires on dom ready and based on different dom dimensions layouts the page.

The problem is, over slow network my js file can fire before `less` js is able to download the  `less` file. Since this is an unknown file type so the browser is not obliged to wait for this file to download and then fire dom ready, even when it is in the `<head>` section. In this scenario my js reads incorrect dimensions since no CSS rules have been applied yet.

So, my query is, how do I know when the `less` file have been downloaded. So that my js code can get fired after `less` has been downloaded and dom is ready.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use less server-side instead of compiling it each time client side. Your users would not be obliged to have js turned on to get css... You may use leesc or lessphp for this.

Comment: Perhaps not an *answer*, so I'll comment: You can bypass this problem entirely by processing the LESS server-side (and caching the result).

Comment: Setting the MIME type for `.less` files to `text/css` on the server side could help.

Comment: Please note that for production server I will indeed use actual css file. This is a development server on the network.

Comment: @Stefan I will try your MIME trick.

Comment: @Stefan It seems I am already using `text/css` MIME, but `rel` in `<link>` is `stylesheet/less`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load less.js rules dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175013/load-less-js-rules-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer to **[this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3178816/1469507)** - sounds like you just need to fire a `less.refreshStyles()` event which will re-compile `<style>` tags with `type="text/less"`.